# Detours alternative for Registry interception

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, detours

I'm looking for a way to intercept and redirect reads to a certain registry keys. Naturally, Detours can do it. But I need it for a commercial application and MS $10K license fee is a bit too steep. Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: What Detours does is not magic. I figured it out before I even knew Detours existed. You might be able to pull off the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Madshi's [madCodeHook](http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I still have to figure out how (and whether) DLL redirection works, but if it does not madCodeHook is probably the best option, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **[EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)** Library might be what you are looking for. It is licensed under **LGPL** and its description sounds quite nice.
I have never actually used it myself because Detours was always enough for my private projects.

There is also an article about it on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/EasyHook64.aspx) but that is rather old and shows only .NET examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Deviare API Hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) if you want to solve also the IPC or [Deviare In-Process](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-in-process-api-hook-library) for a Detours replacement. It's open source and well maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Detours 4 is now open source under the MIT license! So there is no $10k license fee anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Mhook, which is free and works great for both x86 and x64.

Make sure to use [apriorit's fork](http://github.com/apriorit/mhook) of Mhook, it has lots of improvements and bug fixes that are not merged back to the original project.